# Is there a library for urllib2 for python which we can download?

Tags: python, urllib2

I need to use urllib2 with BeautifulSoup. I found the download file for BeautifulSoup and installed it, however, I couldn't find any download files for urllib2, is there another way to intall that module?

Answer (score 11):

The module comes with Python, simply import it:

```
import urllib2
```

If you're using Python3, the `urllib` was replaced by [urllib.request](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html). The Urllib PEP (Python3): http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3108/#urllib-package.

Comment: it does not in windows. Only in *nix

Comment: i used xp. alteast i had to download it.

Comment: Then you either installed Python3 and made a big mistake with getting urllib2 from somewhere in the internet, or you failed hardly to install Python2 correctly.

Comment: If he's using python3, I would hope that installing BeautifulSoup for python2 wouldn't even allow him to import it, though it does make the most sense.  Unless of course he installed it manually

Comment: I get an error:import urllib2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib2
ImportError: No module named 'urllib2'

Comment: So instead of import urllib2, import urllib.request?

Comment: If you are using Python 3, yes. Also click on the links I posted, they bring you to the documentation.

Comment: On windows (unfortunately), import urllib.request does not work.

Comment: @TonyEnnis that has nothing to do with your operating system. You simply have Python 2 installed instead of Python 3.

Comment: No I don't. Python 3.5