# Need to install urllib2 for Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2

I'm running Python 3.5.1 for Mac. I want to use `urllib2` module. I tried installing it but I was told that it's been split into `urllib.request` and `urllib.error` for Python 3.

My command (running from the framework bin directory for now because it's not in my path):

```
sudo ./pip3 install urllib.request
```

Returns this:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib.request (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for urllib.request
```

I got the same error before when I tried to install `urllib2` in one fell swoop.

Comment: Can't you just import `urllib.request` in your Python program?

Comment: urllib.request is part of the standard library and does not need installing.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597865/is-there-a-library-for-urllib2-for-python-which-we-can-download

Comment: urllib is part of std library but it contains only parse package in that, I was not able to find request in that....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a library for urllib2 for python which we can download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597865/is-there-a-library-for-urllib2-for-python-which-we-can-download)

Answer (score 210):

> ***WARNING***: Security researches have found [several poisoned packages on PyPI](http://www.nbu.gov.sk/skcsirt-sa-20170909-pypi/index.html), including a package named `urllib`, which will 'phone home' when installed. *If you used `pip install urllib` some time after June 2017, remove that package **as soon as possible***.

You can't, and you don't need to.

`urllib2` is the name of the library included in Python 2. You can use the [`urllib.request` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) included with Python 3, instead. The `urllib.request` library works the same way `urllib2` works in Python 2. Because it is *already included* you don't need to install it.

If you are following a tutorial that tells you to use `urllib2` then you'll find you'll run into more issues. Your tutorial was written for Python 2, not Python 3. Find a different tutorial, or install Python 2.7 and continue your tutorial on that version. You'll find `urllib2` comes with that version.

Alternatively, install the [`requests` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) for a higher-level and easier to use API. It'll work on both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: so pip is not moderated against malware?

Comment: @igor: `pip` is a command-line tool that can discover and load packages from anywhere. PyPI.org, the default package index `pip` will go to, is not moderated. The Python Software Foundation is a volunteer-run organisation and can't possibly even begin to moderate the amount of code involved.

Answer (score 51):

> In Python 3, `urllib2` was replaced by two in-built modules named `urllib.request` and `urllib.error`

*Adapted from [source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)*

---

So replace this:

```
import urllib2
```

With this:

```py
import urllib.request as urllib2
```

Answer (score 37):

Acording to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

> **Note** The urllib2 module has been split across several modules in Python 3 named `urllib.request` and `urllib.error`. The 2to3 tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3.

So it appears that it is impossible to do what you want but you can use appropriate python3 functions from `urllib.request`.