# Python request.py syntax error

Tags: python

I am new to Python 3.4.5 which I am learning online by watching videos with some good knowledge of C. I am trying to download an image via Python which I am unable to do because of this  error.

Code:

```
import random
import urllib.request

def img(url):
  full='name'+'.jpeg'
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,full)

img("http://lorempixel.com/400/200")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image.py", line 2, in <module>
    import urllib.request
  File "/home/yuvi/pyth/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 69, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
    from email import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/email/utils.py", line 31, in <module>
    import urllib.parse
  File "/home/yuvi/pyth/urllib/parse.py", line 239, in <module>
    _DefragResultBase.url.__doc__ = """The URL with no fragment identifier."""
AttributeError: readonly attribute
```

Comment: You are using the *Python 3 module* in Python 2. You can't, Python 3 code is not backwards compatible. Why are you using the Python 3 standard library in Python 2 in the first place?

Comment: If you are following tutorials that expect you to be using Python 3, then install Python 3 and use that. Don't try to make the Python 3 tutorials work on Python 2.

Comment: Related, in the opposite direction: [Need to install urllib2 for Python 3.5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34475051)

Comment: Thanks for the information.I have installed python 3.4.5 . What would be the code in this case..?

Comment: The code you posted should work directly. I tested it and it saves a `name.jpeg` file.

Comment: So when i run it , it says no module named requests.

Comment: Yet the code you posted here doesn't use `requests`. It uses `http.request` (no s).

Comment: _DefragResultBase.url.__doc__ = """The URL with no fragment identifier."""
AttributeError: readonly attribute

Comment: Sorry, no, I can't help out here, not in comments. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def img(url): full='name'+'.jpeg';urllib.urlretrieve(url,full)
```

`urllib.request` does not exist in Python 2.x, which seems to be your case
so don't try to import that in second line of your code

plus you made a typo (forgot semicolon) which works as a statement separator while writing inline function statements.
Similar to:

```
def img(url):  
  full='name'+'.jpeg'  
  urllib.urlretrieve(url,full)
```

Comment: Huh? Has anyone (apart from you) ever mentioned inline functions here?

Comment: @Melebius you should see the `edited` tag on the question. Prior to edit, it was inline function so had to answer in that form.

Comment: I had opened the post history and found nothing about inline function before I wrote my previous comment.

Comment: @Melebius Well, you could've done better at finding. [have a look](http://askubuntu.com/posts/812417/revisions#spacer-53dbd0aa-9a24-4664-a664-82dc257cad63)