# Urllib2 Module Not Found

Tags: python

I found this python script online that downloads comics. When I tried to run it I got the error:
"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Jake/Desktop/garfield-downloader-master/garfield.py", line 10, in 
import urllib2 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'"
Code is below.

```
from datetime import date,timedelta
import urllib2
import os

def daterange(start,end):
    for x in range(int ((end - start).days)):
        yield start + timedelta(x)

#Create the Directory, if not already existing
dir = "./garfield/"
if not os.path.exists(dir):
    os.makedirs(dir)
    
start_date = date.today()
    
#Garfield Started on 19th June, 1978
start_date = start_date.replace(year=1978,month=6,day=19)
end_date = date.today()

for single_day in daterange(start_date,end_date):
    link = "https://d1ejxu6vysztl5.cloudfront.net/comics/garfield/" + (str(single_day)[:4]) + "/" + str(single_day) + ".gif"
    print(single_day)

    #checks whether the files already exist or not  
    filename = dir+str(single_day)+".gif"
    if not os.path.exists(filename): 
        try:
            f = urllib2.urlopen(link)
        except urllib2.URLError:
            if e.code == 404:
                continue
        print ("Downloading :: " + link)
    
        save_file = open(dir+str(single_day)+".gif","w"+'b')
        save_file.write(f.read())
        save_file.close()

print("Garfield Comics has been downloaded")
```

Comment: Ok, have you installed `urllib2`?

Comment: Please post the output of `<python> -m pip --freeze`, where `<python>` is the Python executable you're using

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date,timedelta
import urllib2
import os

def daterange(start,end):
    for x in range(int ((end - start).days)):
        yield start + timedelta(x)

#Create the Directory, if not already existing
dir = "./garfield/"
if not os.path.exists(dir):
    os.makedirs(dir)
    
start_date = date.today()
    
#Garfield Started on 19th June, 1978
start_date = start_date.replace(year=1978,month=6,day=19)
end_date = date.today()

for single_day in daterange(start_date,end_date):
    link = "https://d1ejxu6vysztl5.cloudfront.net/comics/garfield/" + (str(single_day)[:4]) + "/" + str(single_day) + ".gif"
    print(single_day)

    #checks whether the files already exist or not  
    filename = dir+str(single_day)+".gif"
    if not os.path.exists(filename): 
        try:
            f = urllib2.urlopen(link)
        except urllib2.URLError as e :
            if e == 404:
                continue
        print ("Downloading :: " + link)
    
        save_file = open(dir+str(single_day)+".gif","w"+'b')
        save_file.write(f.read())
        save_file.close()

print("Garfield Comics has been downloaded")
```

This script has a lot of issues but this code here downloads something at least.

urllib2 is a module included with Python 2. So run with Python2 and you'll have no issues aside from some bugs/errors.

Edit: I would be careful when installing urllib packages. From reading/research, some pkgs are deployed as possible malware. [See here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475051/need-to-install-urllib2-for-python-3-5-1)

Answer (score 0):

As the docs state, `urllib2` has been split across several modules in Python 3, namely `urllib.request` and `urllib.error` implementing the same methods you are calling. E.g.,

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
```